# Give authetication to a file in tomcat server

Tags: tomcat

I have one text file and put it into tomcat server root folder. I want to give authentication to that file and how can I access that file after give authentication.

How can I achieve this. Please anyone help.

Comment: The phrase "give authentication" doesn't mean anything. Is the file a document? Is it an executable file? A web page?

Comment: @Bob It Just a text file. "give authentication" - only admin can access that file. User can't access If they know that file location url through view page source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have this project structure:

[image]

And you want to secure the `/folder` to be only accessible to the role `admin` you have to edit your web.xml to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Constraint1</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>file</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/folder/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description/>
            <role-name>admin</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <security-role>
        <description/>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

So if someone without the role `admin` tries to access the file resource it will get this:

[image]

This is role-based authentication.

Of course this is one way. There are also other security mechanism that can be used in tomcat.
For more about tomcat security see these resources

1. http://www.thecoderscorner.com/team-blog/hosting-servers/17-setting-up-role-based-security-in-tomcat#.UcVOspxTrMI
2. http://www.cafesoft.com/products/cams/tomcat-security.html
3. http://www.indicthreads.com/1443/setting-up-secure-web-authentication-in-tomcat/